# Formal versus algebraic good reduction of abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a non-archimedean complete field with ring of integers $k^\circ$, and let $A$ be an abelian variety over $k$. Let $\mathscr A$ be a *formal* abelian model of $A$; i.e., $\mathscr A$ is an abelian formal scheme over $\mathrm{Spf}\;k^\circ$ whose generic fiber is isomorphic to the analytification on $A$ (in your favorite non-archimedean setting: rigid-analytic, Berkovich, whatever...)

Is it then true that $\mathscr A$ is algebraizable; i.e., it is the formal completion of an abelian scheme over $\mathrm{Spec}\;k^\circ$ whose generic fiber is isomorphic to $A$? If $k$ is discretely valued this can be done using the cohomological criterion for good reduction (together with Berkovich's formalism on vanishing cycles, to be used on the formal scheme $\mathscr A$). But in general, I do not see any simple argument. Quite surprisingly (or not), I did not find any mention of this result (let alone a proof) in the various papers/books by Bosch, Lütkebohmert, Raynaud...

Comment: Is there some comparison result between the Picard functor of $\mathscr{A}$ (whatever this means) and that of $A^{\mathrm{an}}$, which should also be that of $A$ by GAGA? Maybe you could then use the fact that $A$ is projective.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly: I think they are isomorphic (I saw this in a paper by Bosch et al.) But I did not find any statement telling that this isomorphism preserves ampleness. 

There is such a result for abelian schemes over a DVR and we can try to adapt the proof (we=myself and Antoine Chambert-Loir; we need such things for computing curvature currents of metrized line bundles on abelian varieties over non-archimedean fields).

Comment: So, there is an invertible sheaf $\mathscr{L}$ on $\mathscr{A}$ whose generic fiber is ample (i.e. is the analytification of an ample $L$ on $A$). Are there comparison theorems for the cohomologies of $\mathscr{L}$ and $L$?

Comment: In any case the above $\mathscr{L}$ is nondegenerate, i.e. the associated morphism  $\phi_\mathscr{L}:\mathscr{A}\to\mathscr{A}'$ is finite ($\mathscr{A}'$= dual of $\mathscr{A}$). To see this, consider the $\ell$-torsion of $\ker\phi_\mathscr{L}$. As a consequence, $H^*(\mathscr{L})$ is $k^\circ$-free and concentrated in one degree, which is zero iff $\mathscr{L}$ is ample.

Comment: We succeeded! Since $\mathscr L_\eta$ is ample, it has a non-zero global section and $\phi_{\mathscr L_\eta}$ is surjective. Then $\mathscr L_s$ also has a non-zero section: pick an effective Cartier divisor in the class of $\mathscr L_\eta$ and consider its (formal) scheme-theoretic closure ; it provides a relative non-zero effective Cartier divisor, whose special fiber gives a non-zero section of  $\mathscr L_s$. Now by surjectivity of the specialization map, the morphism $\phi_{\mathscr L_s}$ is also surjective, hence finite, hence $\mathscr L_s$ is ample, then so is $\mathscr L$.

Comment: I am glad that this very interesting question got answered, and I hope one of the people involved will post an answer. Since the argument is very special to abelian varieties (interpreting ampleness in terms of isogenies), I need to ask: is the result false for smooth and proper formal schemes over $k^\circ$? I.e., does there exist a smooth and proper formal scheme $\mathfrak{X}$ over $k^\circ$ whose rigid generic fiber is algebraizable but which is not itself algebraizable?